# How to translate URL aliases?

Tags: uri, i18n-l10n, transliteration

I have the following path `mysite/basic-page/about-us`
I need translate it to: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the  [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) (Internationalization) module (requires the [Variable](http://drupal.org/project/variable) module).

You can follow this [tutorial](http://renaudjoubert.com/en/article/setting-multilingual-menus-d7).

Comment: @wuchuan if my answer help you don't forget check it as accepted, if you don't know how read this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> Provides one-way string transliteration (romanization) and cleans file names during upload by replacing unwanted characters.
>
> Generally spoken, it takes Unicode text and tries to represent it in US-ASCII characters (universally displayable, unaccented characters) by attempting to transliterate the pronunciation expressed by the text in some other writing system to Roman letters.

Here is a sample of what this module does for "**file names**":

[image]

However, it can also be used to transforms an URL like `mydomain.com/последние-новости-в-Украине-и-мире` in something like `mydomain/poslednie-novosti-v-Ukraine-i-mire`. To do so, you also need to enable the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module. After that, go to the Pathauto setting page and check "Transliterate prior to creating alias". For more details on that, refer to "[D7 Pathauto transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/node/1163118)". **Attention**: this does not "fix" already created aliases (those need to be deleted and recreated).